# Netty Encoder And Decoder using Kryo Serialization

Tags: java, netty, kryo

I am new to Netty 4.0.29 and trying to make Custom Object Encoder and Object Decoder using Kryo as the serialization library and I am unable to make it work. As I am new to Netty maybe that is the reason I am messing up something. I am using **MessageToMessageEncoder** and **MessageToMessageDecoder**

Here is my encoder -

```
public class KryoEncoder extends  MessageToMessageEncoder<Object>{

    private Kryo kryo;
    private Output output;

    public KryoEncoder(Kryo kryo, int bufSize, int maxBufSize) {
        this.kryo = kryo;
        output = new Output(bufSize, maxBufSize);
    }

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg,
            List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        output.clear();
        kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, msg);
        int total = output.position();
        out.add(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(output.getBuffer(), 0 , total));
    }

}
```

Here is the decoder -

```
public class KryoDecoder extends MessageToMessageDecoder<Object>{
    private Kryo kryo;
    private Input input;

    public KryoDecoder (Kryo kryo) {
        this.kryo = kryo;
        input = new Input();
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf buffer = (ByteBuf)msg;
        byte[] ar = new byte[buffer.readableBytes()];
        buffer.readBytes(ar);
        input.read(ar, buffer.readerIndex(), buffer.readableBytes());
        Object object = kryo.readClassAndObject(input);
        buffer.readerIndex(input.position());
        out.add(object);
    }
}
```

Here is the short stack of exception which thrown and I know it is a null pointer exception and somewhere something is wrong in byte array in the decoder but not sure what.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input.read(Input.java:254)
    at TestWithKryo.KryoDecoder.decode(KryoDecoder.java:31)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
    ... 14 more
```

The exception occurs when decoding and I have checked the encoder and checked the channelFuture when sending the encoded object and it did not throw any exception.

Again as I am really new to netty I may have done something really wrong so please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think better for this will be ByteToMessageDecoder and MessageToByteEncoder. Dont forget to send first length of data, or you don't recognize where one packet start and another end. There is my simple example :

```
public class KryoDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

    private final Kryo kryo;

    public KryoDecoder(Kryo kryo) {
        this.kryo = kryo;
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {

        if (in.readableBytes() < 2)
            return;

        in.markReaderIndex();

        int len = in.readUnsignedShort();

        if (in.readableBytes() < len) {
            in.resetReaderIndex();
            return;
        }

        byte[] buf = new byte[len];
        in.readBytes(buf);
        Input input = new Input(buf);
        Object object = kryo.readClassAndObject(input);
        out.add(object);

    }
}
```

and Encoder

```
public class KryoEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<Object> {

    private final Kryo kryo;

    public KryoEncoder(Kryo kryo) {
        this.kryo = kryo;
    }

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object in, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Output output = new Output(outStream, 4096);

        kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, in);
        output.flush();

        byte[] outArray = outStream.toByteArray();
        out.writeShort(outArray.length);
        out.writeBytes(outArray);
    }

}
```

Comment: Also can you just give me a short note on why my solution is not working as I would like to know what was I doing wrong.

Comment: The main problem is use of `input.read(ar, buffer.readerIndex(), buffer.readableBytes());`. You tried to read from buffer in input whitch is null at that point.

Comment: I haven't accepted your answer because as soon as I connect 3 clients the decoder bombs out. Throws a null pointer exception at this line in the decoder
Object object = kryo.readClassAndObject(input);

Comment: Could you send me a full stacktrace of this exception?

Comment: Also just to let you know, I flood server with packets. I send a packet to server and server echoes it back and then from client I echo it back to server. So it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm guess now, do you have same class of serialized object on server and client? I mean same version, no differences? Do you use latest version of Kryo?

Comment: Yes I have the same Class. Here is the link to the project if you want to have a quick look. I am really stuck and have no idea how to proceed. One reason being I can't find an easy to understand guide on Netty. :/
https://www.dropbox.com/s/741ypg3a4r5qozf/NettyPlayground.rar?dl=0

Comment: Sorry, I can't replicate this problem. I use you code and start one server and 5 clients. I tried it for 2 minuts and no error was throw. As I saw in debug prints it was correctly serialized a readed from network.

Comment: I think you have to quickly start the clients and problem will replicate. Thanks by the way :)